# Superderivative of $G^\infty$ maps $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}_\infty\to\mathbb{R}_\infty$

Tags: graded-modules, supergeometry, supermanifolds

I am following Rogers's *Supermanifolds: Theory and Applications* and I might be getting something wrong, because I reach a definition that, as I understand it, doesn't imply what the author states.

Letting $\mathbb{R}_{\infty}$ be a real Grassmann algebra generated by anticommuting $\{\xi_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$, with even and odd parts $\mathbb{R}_{\infty,0}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{\infty,1}$ respectively, we call *superspace* the product
$$\mathbb{R}^{m,n}_{\infty}:= (\mathbb{R}_{\infty,0})^{\times m}\times(\mathbb{R}_{\infty,1})^{\times n}$$
and we specify a point in it as $({\bf x};{\bf \xi})$ for ${\bf x}\in (\mathbb{R}_{\infty,0})^{\times m}$ and ${\bf \xi}\in (\mathbb{R}_{\infty,1})^{\times n}$.

Meanwhile we note $G^\infty(U)$ the $\mathbb{R}_\infty$-module of maps $U\to\mathbb{R}_\infty$ for any open $U$ in a DeWitt supermanifold. Furthermore, the author defines the *superderivative* $\mathcal{D}$ of functions from $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}_\infty$ as acting in the following way:
$$\mathcal{D}f(t;\tau) = \frac{\partial^E}{\partial t} f(t;\tau) + \tau\frac{\partial^O}{\partial \tau} f(t;\tau)$$
where the $E$ (respectively $O$) index of a derivative signals it is even (odd).

Now the author affirms that $\mathcal{D}^2 = \frac{\partial^E}{\partial t}=:\partial_t^E$, but I cannot see that. In my development
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}^2 &= (\partial_t^E)^2 + \tau \partial_t^E\partial_\tau^O + \tau \partial_\tau^O\partial_t^E + \tau \partial_\tau^O - \tau^2(\partial_\tau^O)^2 \\
& = (\partial_t^E)^2 + 2 \tau \partial_t^E\partial_\tau^O + \tau \partial_\tau^O
\end{align}$$
because, as far as I understand, $\tau$ being odd implies $\tau^2 = 0$, and even derivatives commute with odd derivatives as well as with odd scalars. This result is visibly not equal to $\partial_t^E$. What is wrong?

Comment: The relevant passage is found in section 6.3 of the first edition of the book.

Comment: If we consider the classical function f(t) would D just be d/dt?

Comment: Then why $D^2=d/dt$ not obviously wrong? Since in this case $D^2=d^2/dt^2$.

Comment: ‍♂️ That this might be some sort of typo is not impossible, but I prefer letting that be the last possible explanation. Another problem is I have not found an *errata* of the book.

Comment: Also, I was probably wrong when I said $D$ reduces to $\partial_t$ on classical functions, first and foremost because classical functions are absent on the space on which $D$ acts; the closest thing to a classical function in $G^\infty$ is its Grassmanian continuation. Also note that $t$ is not a real number (nor in any $\mathbb{R}^n$), so you shouldn't think that a $G^\infty$‐function of $t$ that is independent of $\tau$ is a classical function.

Comment: In case you were curious, @LidingYao, you can check below to see what the problem was.

Comment: I am actually more interested in what is the way to settle down the non-uniqueness of the odd derivative on supermanifold. I knew a bit for supermanifolds from my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further reading and waking up this morning with an epiphany, I have arrived to the conclusion that the problem is double: in one hand I was misunderstanding some notions, and in the other the author committed a typo. Here I present the solution.

First and foremost, I got wrong what is meant by $\mathcal{D}^2$. The space of derivations $D(\mathbb{R}^{1,1})$ to which  $\mathcal{D}^2$ belongs is not a super algebra over $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ but a super Lie module over $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$, so by  $\mathcal{D}^2$ one should understand $[\mathcal{D},\mathcal{D}]$, for the corresponding super Lie bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]$. The latter, for any two derivations $\delta_1, \delta_2$ and with $|\cdot|$ being the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded degree, is specifically defined as
$$[\delta_1, \delta_2] :=\delta_1 \delta_2 - (-1)^{|\delta_1||\delta_2|}\delta_2\delta_1.\tag{1}$$
Secondly, the author seems to have committed a typo, as confirmed by the expressions used later in the same book, and the proper definition of $\mathcal{D}$ is
$$\mathcal{D}:= \partial^O_\tau + \tau\partial_t^E.\tag{2}$$
Consequently, dropping the indices $E$ and $O$ for notational convenience and considering that $|\partial_\tau|=|\tau|=1$ while $|\partial_t|=0$, we combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to obtain
$$\begin{split}
\mathcal{D}^2&=[\partial_\tau,\partial_\tau]+ [\partial_\tau, \tau\partial_t] +  [\tau\partial_t, \partial_\tau] + \underbrace{[\partial_t, \partial_t]}_{=0}\\
&=(2\underbrace{\partial_\tau\partial_\tau}_{=0})+(\partial_t-\tau\partial_t\partial_\tau +\tau\partial_t\partial_\tau)+(\tau\partial_t\partial_\tau+\partial_t-\tau\partial_t\partial_\tau)\\
&=2\partial_t
\end{split}$$
In the context of supergeometry it is not uncommon to say that the superderivative $(2)$—modulo a factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$—*is the square root of the classical derivative* $\partial_t$ precisely because $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathcal{D})^2=\partial_t$.